# LINQtoSQL - Keeps self referencing

Tags: json, linq-to-sql

I have two tables which are linked together by a OneToMany relationship. Table1 has a foreign key to Table2's Primary key.

When i use LINQtoSQL to get the a row in Table1 it automatically gets Table2's data with it.. Table2 references rows in Table1, which it also tries to get.. And there we go, an infinite loop

```
Guid productIdGuid = Guid.Parse(productId);
var info = (from row in db.Info
where row.ProductId == productIdGuid &&
row.ComputerId == null &&
row.DeletedAt == null
select row).FirstOrDefault();                
return license;
```

I get a stackoverflow error when i then convert info to JSON, with the following:

```
JsonConvert.SerializeObject(info);
```

Which i however can resolve by this:

```
JsonConvert.SerializeObject(input, Formatting.Indented,
    new JsonSerializerSettings
    {
        ReferenceLoopHandling = ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore,
        PreserveReferencesHandling = PreserveReferencesHandling.Objects
    });
```

But the result here doesn't look too good

```
{  
   "$id":"1",
   "ProductId":"a8a78902-777c-4be9-a240-a5e47af6f144",
   "ComputerId":null,
   "Table2":{  
      "$id":"2",
      "Id":"a8a78902-777c-4be9-a240-a5e47af6f144",
      "Reference":"10456975",
      "Table1":[  
         {  
            "$id":"3", 
            "ProductId":"a8a78902-777c-4be9-a240-a5e47af6f144",
            "ComputerId":"63e57ee7-14d3-e611-80dc-0050569ea396",
            "Table2":{  
               "$ref":"2"
            }
         },
         {  
            "$ref":"1"
         },
         .....
      ]
   }
}
```

I dont want it to continue getting childs/links between the tables. I only want the one link, so that the result comes to look like this:

```
{  
   "$id":"1",
   "ProductId":"a8a78902-777c-4be9-a240-a5e47af6f144",
   "ComputerId":null,
   "Table2":{  
      "$id":"2",
      "Id":"a8a78902-777c-4be9-a240-a5e47af6f144",
      "Reference":"10456975",          
   }
}
```

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

you could add `[JsonIgnore]` attribute in your Table2 class to all the properties you want to ignore which in your case would be the Table1 reference

```
public class Table2
{
    ...

    [JsonIgnore] 
    public ICollection<Table1> Table1 { get; set; }

    ...
}
```

Comment: If i enter this nothing changes unfortunately. I still get child reference